Meaning of 勸諭, especially 諭
勸諭 generally means to persuade/educate? Am I right here?
I don't understand what 諭 means exactly. Also, what is the difference between 諭 and 喻? 比喻 means metaphor, which I fully understand.

Try checking each character in this post individually, and see if you can find the answer yourself. That's what I would do if I wanted to answer it

諭 and 喻 mean exactly the same thing and can be interchanged? Thanks.


古同“喻”，比方。

In modern Chinese language, 諭 and 喻  have different meanings

諭:
instruct; order. Example: 手諭 (written order/ instruction); 口諭(verbal order/ instruction)


喻:
(1) explain; make clear; (2) understand; comprehend; (3) draw an analogy; be compared to


勸 = persuade; advise

諭 = instruct --> explain --> reasoning

勸諭 is a compound word, meaning "to persuade or advice with reasons"


勸 - persuade (with or without stating reasons)
勸諭 - persuade (also stating reasons)

諭/谕 : https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%B0%95



告诉，使人知道; 开导, 如: "晓喻"




古同“喻”，明白，理解。




古同“喻”，比方。



勸諭 - 劝勉(advise and encourage)晓喻(and enlighten) https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%8B%B8%E8%AB%AD
